Using @Autowired in abstract class with generics: 'No beans of Generic type found' warning in IntelliJ but autowiring still works
Edit: One detail I missed out. The warning that I'm seeing is reported by IntelliJ. I have also seen others mention using the Spring Data plugin but I already have that.
Let's say I have ten controllers that want to autowire to ten services. The controllers and services act very similarly, they just differ in the type of object or DTO they deal with (and the DTOs themselves are very similar too). So I create an abstract controller like so:
public abstract class BaseController<S extends BaseService, D extends BaseDTO> {
  @Autowired
  protected S service;

  @GetMapping("/getThing")
  public D getThing(@PathVariable id) {
    Object thing = service.getById(id);
    // ...convert thing to DTO
    return dto;
  }
}

I put the @RestController annotation on the subclasses.
Then, I also create an abstract service:
public abstract class BaseService<R extends JpaRepository<O extends Object, Long>> {
  @Autowired
  protected R repository;

  public O getById(Long id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
  }
}

And I put @Service on the subclasses.
So the purpose of extending the BaseRepository and BaseService is to provide the actual classes of the DTO and Repository into the generics of the abstract classes.
When I do this, I get the following warning:
Could not autowire. No beans of 'S' type found.
Same warning for 'R' for my BaseService.
But when I build and run, the autowiring seems to work fine. My controller and my service works. And when I debug to check the actual bean that got autowired, they seem to be of the correct types.
I have tried moving @Service to BaseService, and also on both BaseService and the subclasses, but it doesn't seem to change anything.
I understand that in typical cases, constructor injection is preferred. However, if I do that, I'd have to implement very similar constructors ten times for each controller or service. Yes, I do know that constructor injection is still preferred for other reasons. And I understand that the error is technically valid. But for my question, what I want to focus on is this:
Do the inner-workings of Spring really work properly if I autowire it like this? If so, then what is the reason that the warning gets generated? And if code brevity is my utmost concern, then is my best solution to just suppress the warning using @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")?

Where/when do you get the warning? If there is no bean, it cannot be autowired. If it can be autowired, then the warning doesn't make sense.

IntelliJ is the one giving me the warning

Then the question should mention it. I think IntelliJ has its own rules/engine to evaluate the available beans that doesn't necessarily match the actual logic used by the Spring framework.

That is a good point, sorry I forgot to mention that. And that's an interesting point that IntelliJ evaluates the autowire differently. I still hope someone could enlighten me if the implementation I have is still assured to work correctly.

Well, you wrote yourself "But when I [build and] run, the autowiring seems to work fine." – so you already have proof that the autowiring works, don't you?

Yes, I'm just worried if there's other niche behaviour which is broken. I guess unit testing will reveal that.
